# Two python pools, two queues

Tags: python, queue, pool

I am trying to understand how pool and queue work in Python, and the following example doesn't work as expected. I expect the program to end, but it's stuck in an infinite loop because the second queue isn't getting emptied.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

inq = multiprocessing.Queue()
outq = multiprocessing.Queue()

def worker_main(q1, q2):
    while True:
        i = q1.get(True)
        time.sleep(.1) 
        q2.put(i*2)

def worker2(q):
    print q.get(True)

p1 = multiprocessing.Pool(3, worker_main,(inq, outq,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Pool(2, worker2,(outq,))


for i in range(50):
    inq.put(i)


while inq.qsize()>0 or outq.qsize()>0:
    print 'q1 size', inq.qsize(), 'q2 size', outq.qsize()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

the output shows that the second queue (outq) is .get once, but that's all.

output:

> ```
> q1 size 49 q2 size 0
> q1 size 47 q2 size 0
> 2
> 4
> q1 size 44 q2 size 1
> q1 size 41 q2 size 4
> q1 size 38 q2 size 7
> q1 size 35 q2 size 11
> q1 size 31 q2 size 14
> q1 size 27 q2 size 18
> q1 size 24 q2 size 21
> q1 size 22 q2 size 23
> q1 size 19 q2 size 26
> q1 size 15 q2 size 30
> q1 size 12 q2 size
> ```

Why isn't the worker2 getting called until the outq is empty?

Comment: You only wrote your `worker2` to retrieve 1 item.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `multiprocessing.pool` is for. You're using it just to create a bunch of processes, but it already has the queues you're adding on top. Try not giving it an initializer function and instead calling `pool.map` and passing in a sequence of data. It will use its own queues to pass the values in and get the return values back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very odd way to use a `Pool`.  The function passed to the constructor is called only once per process in the pool.  It's intended for one-time initialization tasks, and is rarely used.

As is, your `worker2` is called exactly twice, one time for each process in yout `p2` pool.  Your function gets one value from a queue and then exits.  The process never does anything else.  So it's doing exactly what you coded it to do.

There's no evident reason to use a `Pool` here at all; creating 5 `multiprocessing.Process` objects instead would be more natural.

If you feel you have to do it this way, then you need to put a loop in `worker2`.  Here's one way:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker_main(q1, q2):
    while True:
        i = q1.get()
        if i is None:
            break
        time.sleep(.1) 
        q2.put(i*2)

def worker2(q):
    while True:
        print(q.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inq = multiprocessing.Queue()
    outq = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Pool(3, worker_main,(inq, outq,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Pool(2, worker2,(outq,))

    for i in range(50):
        inq.put(i)
    for i in range(3): # tell worker_main we're done
        inq.put(None)

    while inq.qsize()>0 or outq.qsize()>0:
        print('q1 size', inq.qsize(), 'q2 size', outq.qsize())
        time.sleep(.1)
```

### SUGGESTED

This is a "more natural" way to use `Process` objects instead, and using queue sentinels (special values - here `None`) to let processes know when to stop.  BTW, I'm using Python 3, so use `print` as a function rather than as a statement.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker_main(q1, q2):
    while True:
        i = q1.get()
        if i is None:
            break
        time.sleep(.1) 
        q2.put(i*2)

def worker2(q):
    while True:
        i = q.get()
        if i is None:
            break
        print(i)

def wait(procs):
    alive_count = len(procs)
    while alive_count:
        alive_count = 0
        for p in procs:
            if p.is_alive():
                p.join(timeout=0.1)
                print('q1 size', inq.qsize(), 'q2 size', outq.qsize())
                alive_count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inq = mp.Queue()
    outq = mp.Queue()
    p1s = [mp.Process(target=worker_main, args=(inq, outq,))
           for i in range(3)]
    p2s = [mp.Process(target=worker2, args=(outq,))
           for i in range(2)]
    for p in p1s + p2s:
        p.start()

    for i in range(50):
        inq.put(i)
    for p in p1s: # tell worker_main we're done
        inq.put(None)

    wait(p1s)
    # Tell worker2 we're done
    for p in p2s:
        outq.put(None)
    wait(p2s)
```